# How do I log Grails command object errors?

Tags: validation, grails, logging

What is the most effective way to log a command object with errors in Grails?

My current logging is just,

```
if (!cmd.validate()) log.debug("command invalid ${cmd.errors}")
```

but it just spews out an unreadable mess of output.

Anyone have any suggestions to improve logging of command objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a dependency injection for the `messageSource` bean:

```
def messageSource
```

and then you can build a map keyed by field name with the validation errors for that field:

```
def locale = Locale.default
def stringsByField = [:].withDefault { [] }
for (fieldErrors in cmd.errors) {
   for (error in fieldErrors.allErrors) {
      stringsByField[error.field] << messageSource.getMessage(error, locale)
   }
}
```

and you can just run `println stringsByField` or look for individual problems by key.

Here I'm using the default Locale, but if you're using localization use the current one for the request.

Answer (score 4):

```
cmd.errors.allErrors.each {
    log.debug it
}
```

**Edit** (More Verbose)

```
cmd.errors.allErrors.each {err ->
    log.debug("[$err.field]: $err")
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `log.debug(cmd.errors.allErrors)` be an easier way to do this?

Comment: You would end up spewing again. Iterating over each `error` you could get an handle on each `field` (synonymous to what @Burt has mentioned in his answer) and `log` according to your need. See my edit.